# SQL query: Recode value as new variable

Tags: sql-server

I am using a database that consist of answers to customer questionnaires. My problem is that while the customers has been asked several questions each, the number and specific questions vary and each question has its own record. So each questionnaire has three questions.

I have grouped the question types and want one record for each questionnaire with all the answers.

If qnumber [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9] are the same and the info is like this

```
ID,qnumber,avalue  
1,1,4  
1,4,5  
1,7,6  
2,2,5  
2,5,6  
2,8,7  
3,3,7  
3,6,8  
3,9,9
```

I want to construct the query so a get a result like this:

```
ID,q1,q2,q3  
1,4,5,6  
2,5,6,7  
3,6,7,8
```

Is that even possible?

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: What is your conversion logic? How qnumber and avalue transformed to q1, q2, q3 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;With cte(ID,qnumber,avalue  )
AS
(
SELECT 1,1,4  UNION ALL
SELECT 1,4,5  UNION ALL
SELECT 1,7,6  UNION ALL
SELECT 2,2,5  UNION ALL
SELECT 2,5,6  UNION ALL
SELECT 2,8,7  UNION ALL
SELECT 3,3,7  UNION ALL
SELECT 3,6,8  UNION ALL
SELECT 3,9,9  
)
SELECT Cstring AS CombinedValue
    ,SUBSTRING(Cstring, 0, CHARINDEX(',', Cstring)) AS ID
    ,SUBSTRING(Cstring, CHARINDEX(',', Cstring) + 1, CHARINDEX(',', Cstring) - 1) AS Q1
    ,SUBSTRING(Cstring, CHARINDEX(',', Cstring) + 5, CHARINDEX(',', Cstring) - 1) AS Q2
    ,SUBSTRING(Cstring, CHARINDEX(',', Cstring) + 9, CHARINDEX(',', Cstring) - 1) AS Q2
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT STUFF((
                SELECT ',' + CAST(qnumber AS VARCHAR) + ',' + CAST(avalue AS VARCHAR)
                FROM cte i
                WHERE i.ID = o.ID
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 1, '') AS Cstring
    FROM cte o
    ) DT
```

Result

```
  CombinedValue    ID   Q1  Q2  Q2
    ------------------------------
    1,4,4,5,7,6     1   4   5   6
    2,5,5,6,8,7     2   5   6   7
    3,7,6,8,9,9     3   7   8   9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    ID  INT,
    qnumber INT,
    avalue  INT
)

INSERT #Temp
VALUES 
(1,1,4),
(1,4,5),
(1,7,6),
(2,2,5),
(2,5,6),
(2,8,7),
(3,3,7),
(3,6,8),
(3,9,9)


SELECT ID, [1] AS q1, [2] AS q2, [3] AS q3
FROM (
    SELECT ID, [1], [2], [3]
    FROM (
        SELECT ID, 
            CASE WHEN qnumber IN (1, 2, 3) THEN 1
                 WHEN qnumber IN (4, 5, 6) THEN 2
                 WHEN qnumber IN (7, 8, 9) THEN 3
            END AS qnumber,
            avalue
        FROM #Temp) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT
    (AVG(avalue)
    FOR qnumber IN ([1], [2], [3])) AS PivotTable
) t

DROP TABLE #Temp
```